# insert into access table syntax error where

Tags: syntax

i want to insert some data in access table but it gives me syntax error for my insert into staatements....
so i share my code to you and hope you can help me....

`private OleDbConnection conn;
        public Form1()
        {
         InitializeComponent();
        }`

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
      `Data Source=D:\\Database3.mdb;Persist Security Info=False");
    }`

      `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`
    {
        conn.Open();

        string query = "INSERT INTO Table([Kaargah],[Manager])" +
                       "VALUES('"+textBox1.Text+"','"+textBox2.Text+"')";

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.CommandText = query;
        command.Connection = conn;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("داده‌ها با موفقیت ثبت گردید!");

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your table name to anything other than 'Table'. Like this... Some name such as 'Table' are probably reserved. Avoid using such names.

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Table1([Kaargah],[Manager]) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

well you can write below query it is fine

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Table1([Kaargah],[Manager]) VALUES('textBox1.Text','textBox2.Text')";
```